# Node.JS variables inside HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I used Express to generate simple site. I realized that there is possibility to use Node.js variables, but using Jade.

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
   res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

And index file:

```
extends layout

block content
h1= title
p Welcome to #{title}
```

So, as I understand, in res.render() first argument is files name and second - variables that I want to use when I render site.

Can I do the same, but using HTML instead of Jade?  Can I include some nodejs data inside html file? How?

Comment: Check out the EJS template engine.. the markup is more HTML-ish: https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs

Comment: thanks @Skelly that's what I want

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Jade is a template engine. It is designed to be an intermediary between a programming language and a data format.

HTML is a data format.

---

You could generate all your HTML by concatenating strings together, but that involves a lot of work and some ugly code … which is why people use template engines.

---

You could use a *different* template engine (such as [moustache](http://mustache.github.io/)) which allows you to have a more HTML-like syntax.